# fs.writeFile not working when the file path has a folder with timestamp

Tags: node.js, filesystems

I am trying to write a data to a file which is inside the folder with folder name having timestamp.

```
 fs.writeFileSync(`.files/${process.env.TIMESTAMP}/data.txt`, "Welcome", 
      "utf8", function (err) {
           if (err) {
             return console.log(err);
           }
      });
```

and as time stamp i mentioned as

```
`${new Date().toLocaleDateString()}_${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}`;
```

There is no error displayed, but its not getting written. If i remove and give as below : its works

```
fs.writeFileSync('.files/data.txt', "Welcome", 
      "utf8", function (err) {
           if (err) {
             return console.log(err);
           }
      });
```

Please help me to understand how to give with timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

In first case , the reason is that you are trying to write in to a folder which is not present at all.There is no folder inside files with name ${process.env.TIMESTAMP}.

First create a directory with name as required by you and then try writing into a file in that folder

Do something like this

```
var dir = `.files/${process.env.TIMESTAMP}`;

if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
}

fs.writeFileSync(`.files/` + dir + `/data.txt`, "Welcome", 
      "utf8", function (err) {
           if (err) {
             return console.log(err);
           }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have couple errors in your code:

1) [writeFileSync(file, data[, options])](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) doesn't have callback as third argument. Callback argument exists only for async version of this method [writeFile(file, data[, options], callback)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback).

In this case you should get exception if there will be error:

```
fs.writeFileSync(`.files/${process.env.TIMESTAMP}/data.txt`, "Welcome", "utf8");
```

2) This expression could produce not valid folder name:

```
`${new Date().toLocaleDateString()}_${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}`
```

In my browser it produced:

```
"6/25/2019_2:01:44 PM"
```

But here is [rules for folder and files names](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linuxunix-rules-for-naming-file-and-directory-names/) in UNIX systems which says:

> 4. In short, filenames may contain any character except / (root directory), which is reserved as the separator between files and directories in a pathname. You cannot use the null character.

You should make more safe directory name. Use this approach:

```
`${d.getFullYear()}_${d.getMonth()}_${d.getDate()}__${d.getHours()}_${d.getMinutes()}`
```

`_` - is allowed character for folders and files names.

3) You need create directory using [mkdirSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_options) before creating files in it